# Rationals as a direct sum of two proper subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Prove that the group $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is not isomorphic to the direct sum of two proper subgroups.

**My approach:** Suppose that $\mathbb{Q}=A\oplus B$ where $A,B$ - proper subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$. By the definition it means that each $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ has unique representation, i.e. if $q=a_1+b_1$ and $q=a_2+b_2$ then $a_1=a_2$, $b_1=b_2$. Since $1\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $0\in A$ then $1=0+1$ where $1\in B$. Since $2=1+1\in B$ hence $1=(-1)+2$ and so $-1\in A$. We get two distinct representations, contradiction.

**Remark:** Please do not duplicate this question. I have sen some topics with this question but i did not saw the solution similar to above.

What's wrong with this solution?

Answer (score 3):

Following somewhat your idea, but aboiding the trap you fell into:

Assume $\Bbb Q=A\oplus B$ with $A,B$ non-trivial subgroups of $\Bbb Q$. Pick $0\ne a\in A$, $0\ne b\in B$. Then $a=\frac nm$, $b=\frac pq$ for suitable non-zero integers $n,m,p,q$. Then
$$np=\underbrace{a+a+\ldots+a}_{mp} =\underbrace{b+b+\ldots+b}_{nq}\in A\cap B,$$
contradiction.

Comment: That's what I want to do but as you said I fell into trap. Very good point!

Answer (score 2):

You assert $1 \in B$, but there's no reason to think this is true.

Comment: It is by the definition of a proper subgroup, it must contain the multiplicative identity.

Comment: Maybe because I am not understand the idea of direct sum correctly. But why it is not true? we take $1\in \mathbb{Q}$ and there exists unique pair of $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $1=a+b$. Taking $a=0$ we get $b=1$. Not?

Comment: @Mathaddict The question speaks of the group $\mathbb Q$ under addition, so there's no multiplication to consider.

Comment: Ahh. I guess that I got because we have no information about these $a$ and $b$, right? We have no right take value $a=0$.

Comment: @ZFR You don't get to choose any $a \in A$, just a specific pair $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Maybe it's $a=\frac25$ and $b=\frac35$.

Comment: @ZFR That is exactly right.

Comment: @ZFR There needs to some $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $1 = a + b$.  There is no need for $a = 0$.  Remember that when considered as additive groups, $1$ is not special.  If this were true for $1$ then it would be true for everything.

Comment: But how to solve this problem?

Comment: @ZFR There are several ways. One way is to use the fact that $A$ and $B$ must have trivial intersection. Take arbitrary nonzero $a\in A$ and $b\inB$, then use their LCD to demonstrate nontrivial intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

We claim $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ can *not* be the direct product of two non-trivial subgroups.

Suppose we two subgroups $H, K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $Q \cong H \times K$. Then, there would be a homomorphism $h : \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow K$ with kernel $H$. But since any non-zero homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ to $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ is always bijective, we conclude $H = \{0\}$, which is a contradiction.